# Is this house completely out of the 'game'?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones Season 7 Episode 2 ["Stormborn"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormborn) we see that:

> Euron Greyjoy raids Yara Greyjoy's fleet, and manages to capture the current ruler of Dorne; Ellaria Sand, as well as her daughters, two of which are killed in the raid, and one is captured along with Ellaria and Yara.

In the following episode we see that:

> Euron gifts Ellaria and Tyene (her surviving daughter) to Cersei, who are then quickly imprisoned and tortured.

This presumably leaves

> Dorne

without a current ruler, at-least until another steps up to take power. However, this does not necessarily mean that this kingdom doesn't have any current military power. Do the events mentioned above totally negate the potential power of this kingdom, or would it still benefit Daenerys to ally with what's left of this kingdom?

Also, given the current situation, who, if anyone, is next in line to take power in this kingdom. And, would this person be likely to ally themselves with Daenerys?

Comment: To those silent parties voting to close this as being primarily opinion-based. What can I do to rephrase the question to not be primarily opinion-based? Or is this a case where it's beyond repair?

Comment: Out-of-universe - since we already saw Dorne getting much lighter, casual, passing treatment than in the books, there's no reason to think that was anything but a way to discard a thread they already decided they couldn't fully develop or do justice to.  They needed it, because the Viper vs Mountain was so major, as was Marcella being there, but once that wrapped, there was no place for them.  A shame, but those are the limitations of a show, both budget and time.  Maybe that's one of the spin-offs they are looking at.

Comment: My guess is that it's being voted to close as 'Future Works' - presumably this will be answered at some point during the show.

Comment: I went through with closure as [future works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based) (there's no official closure reason for that). It's pretty obvious this will be covered in a future episode. At that time, I would say a reopen would be in order. Just let it sit for now.

Answer (score 6):

**For all intents and purposes, yes, they are "out of the game".**

[House Martell](http://showcase.gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Martell) is considered extinct as the ruling Prince (Doran) was overthrown and he and his heir (Trystane) were murdered which leaves no heirs to the family.

At this point in time the remaining houses of Dorne are likely in shock or civil war. The lords of the sworn houses would likely call their own troops home to protect what is left of their own house.

I would think none of the Dornish Houses would swear fealty to the Lannisters after what Cersei did and Tywin before her. The Targaryens have a better chance of gaining whomever takes control of Dorne as an ally. Even though the Martells are extinct the remaining houses would have had the trickle-down benefits of being loyal to and married into the crown.

In the end we do not currently know who will be the next ruling house of Dorne, if any. I expect it will be the one who offers the most to the winner of the war between Daenrys and Cersei.